# How to change the indice order of a rank 3 tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am new to tensor analysis,

Suppose I have a contravariant Tensor say $X^{ijk}$, in order to do the indices contraction, I may have to calculate $X^{jik}g_{j} = X^{ik}$ (Einstein summation omitted here), then how should I generate the $X^{jik}$ from $X^{ijk}$?  Is there any rule for that? is that symmetrical principle?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation whatsoever between $X^{ijk}$ and $X^{jik}$ as stated. A given tensor need not be symmetric or skew-symmetric for any choices of indices.

Also, your $X^{jik}g_j = X^{ik}$ is not correct, as the metric tensor is a tensor of order $2$. What would make sense is to write $X^{jik}g_{k\ell} = X^{ji}_{\phantom{ji}\ell}$ instead.

For better or worse, [I have some notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/tensors.pdf) about tensors on vector spaces, you might find that useful.

Comment: Thank you Ivo, it is a very explanation useful particularly for the beginner. Then I have further concern, my target is to make a tensor that the summation of each of its face is equal, say $\sum X^{ij} = \sum X^{ik} =\sum X^{kj}$. How could I define an operation to represent this? say how to calculate the summation of $X^{ij}$ from $X^{ijk}$? Thank you !

Comment: You can't write both $X^{ij}$ and $X^{ijk}$: either $X$ is a tensor of rank $2$ or of rank $3$. You can perform a contraction between an upper and a lower index, or between two upper or lower indices (provided you have a scalar product). Also, writing things as $\sum X^{ij}$ is unnatural from the perspective of Einstein's convention, and if you actually meant $$\sum_{i,j} X^{ij}=\sum_{i,k} X^{ik}=\sum_{k,j}X^{kj},$$this is trivially true, as all the indices are dummy indices there.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the contraction product $ X^{ijk} g_{il}  = X^{jk}_l$ which stands for the $\sum_{i,j} X^{ij}$ by $l$?  Therefore, if I want to present what I want above, is it possible to write down like $ X^{ijk} g_{il}  = X^{jk}_l = X^{ijk} g_{kl}  = X^{ij}_l=X^{ijk} g_{jl}  = X^{ik}_l $?